# deliveries quote 404 Not Found

Tags: php, uber-api

deliveries quote 404 Not Found
     we call deliveries quote API, we getting following 404 errors
     https://api.uber.com/v1/deliveries/quote

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://api.uber.com/v1/deliveries/quote` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: 404 page not found ' in /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3 /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/vendor/gu in /home/mealhi5/domains/mealhi5.com/public_html/libraries/uber/src/Client.php on line 173
```

We are using following sample code to work out, let me know what could be issue.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Stevenmaguire\Uber\Client(array(

'access_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

'server_token' => 'xxxxxxx',

'use_sandbox'  => false, // optional, default false

'version'      => 'v1', // optional, default 'v1.2'

'locale'       => 'en_US', // optional, default 'en_US'

));


$data['items'][0]['title'] = 'Chocolate bar';
$data['items'][0]['quantity'] = 1;
$data['items'][0]['price'] = 10;
$data['items'][0]['currency_code'] = 'USD';

$data['pickup']['contact']['first_name'] = 'xxxxx';
$data['pickup']['contact']['last_name'] = 'xxxxxx';
$data['pickup']['contact']['phone']['number'] = 'xxxxxx';
$data['pickup']['contact']['contact'] = 'Sri Surati Thali';
$data['pickup']['location']['address'] = '138 S Main St';
$data['pickup']['location']['city'] = 'Milpitas';
$data['pickup']['location']['state'] = 'CA';
$data['pickup']['location']['postal_code'] = '95035';
$data['pickup']['location']['country'] = 'US';

$data['dropoff']['contact']['first_name'] = 'xxxx';
$data['dropoff']['contact']['last_name'] = 'xxxx';
$data['dropoff']['contact']['phone']['number'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$data['dropoff']['location']['address'] = '399 Silicon Valley Blvd';
$data['dropoff']['location']['city'] = 'San Jose';
$data['dropoff']['location']['state'] = 'CA';
$data['dropoff']['location']['postal_code'] = '95138';
$data['dropoff']['location']['country'] = 'US';

$products = $client->deliveriesquote($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that endpoint is adding new people, see this article for example: http://fortune.com/2018/03/31/uber-ending-uberrush-delivery-service/

In addition, in the scope list for delivery it mentions: "Including access to your route information for any delivery in progress. Your Uber account will be charged for any deliveries processed. Selecting this scope will only provide access to the sandbox. For full access, apply here."

So it does not seem like you should move forward with delivery testing. Hope that helps.